# Updating Laravel Homestead error: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to update Laravel Homestead with `vagrant box update` command. It used to work for me in the past, but now it gives me the error:

```
~/Homestead: vagrant box update
==> homestead-7: Checking for updates to 'laravel/homestead'
    homestead-7: Latest installed version: 2.1.0
    homestead-7: Version constraints: >= 1.0.0
    homestead-7: Provider: virtualbox
There was an error while downloading the metadata for this box.
The error message is shown below:

The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized
```

Why is this error produced? What should I be authorized to?

Comment: Hashicorp migrated atlas.hashicorp.com afterwards we got this error.

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: There should be a new url for the box in the Vagrantfile. Didn't find it yet.

Comment: Or maybe no url at all.

Comment: I just deleted the box, migrated my Atlas account to Vagrant Cloud and downloaded the box again. Now it should be okay :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone ends up here, here is what i have done on my pc (linux ubuntu distro) :

1) edited the file corresponding to the virtual os i was trying to "vagrant up" :
"vim ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/geerlingguy-VAGRANTSLASH-centos7/1.2.9/virtualbox/box.ovf", line 122 added 
2) in case you have an older version of virtualbox, after the image was downloaded go to vb, right click on the image > setttings > network and click the checkbox
selection_102
[Virtualbox version lower than 5.xx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgrQx.png)

3) go to vagrantcloud.com create an account
4) go to your folder which contains the Vagrantfile and in a terminal write "vagrant login", enter your credentials
5) vagrant up to start your vm, vagrant ssh hostname ......
and you're good to go.....at least i was :)